# Cannot read property 'author' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js

I use the events folder and would like to have logs to delete messages.

But unfortunately I get this error when someone deletes a message:

`TypeError: cannot read property 'author' of undefined`

Does anyone know what to do about this please?

Code:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js') 

module.exports = async(guild, interaction, user, client, message, messageDelete, author) => {

  let DeleteEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  .setTitle("**SMAZANÁ ZPRÁVA**")
  .setColor("#fc3c3c")
  .addField(`Autor:`, `${message.author.tag}`, true)
  .addField(`Kanál:`, `${message.channel}`, true)
  .addField(`Zpráva:`, `${message.content}`);

  let DeleteChannel = client.channels.cache.get("969632261446176848").send({embeds: [DeleteEmbed]});
}
```

Comment: `message` must be the value `undefined`, which means there is no property `author`.  Check your function input to see why `message` doesn't have a value

Comment: Thank you, but I'm sorry... I don't understand what you're trying to say.

Comment: What Dave is trying to say, for some reason the `message` parameter you are passing seems to be `undefined`, you will have to check it's value when you call the function

Comment: Oh, okay. Thank you. But how can I do that?

Comment: The function may be receiving the explicit value `undefined` in the 5th parameter (`message`), or it may not be being called with at least 5 parameters (in which case the value is implicitly `undefined`).  Or it may not be an object (`typeof message !== 'object'`) which can prevent the `author` property from being dereferenced.  You need to look at the call stack to determine what, if anything, is being passed

Comment: try to console log it for start to see the value, and then try to see where it's called, use console.trace() if you need to

Comment: I'm really sorry, but I don't think we understand each other. I'm communicating with a translator and I don't know what to do because this is the first time I've heard about this in my life.

Answer (score 0):

You get your error because `message` is undefined. Simply check your function inputs before adding the related fields:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js') 

module.exports = async(guild, interaction, user, client, message, messageDelete, author) => {

  let DeleteEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  .setTitle("**SMAZANÁ ZPRÁVA**")
  .setColor("#fc3c3c");
  if (message && message.author)
    DeleteEmbed.addField(`Autor:`, `${message.author.tag}`, true)
  if (message && message.channel)
    DeleteEmbed.addField(`Kanál:`, `${message.channel}`, true)
  if (message && message.content)
    DeleteEmbed.addField(`Zpráva:`, `${message.content}`);

  let DeleteChannel = client.channels.cache.get("969632261446176848").send({embeds: [DeleteEmbed]});
}
```